# mp4 file cannot be played in the flowplayer fancybox plugin

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

I am encountering an issue that .mp4 video file can not be loaded in the flowplayer within the fancybox plugin.

Chrome and IE: the loading images keep making circle but a message shows that the mp4 video file

Firefox: white blank box

my site is: http://www.globalbest.com.hk/magazine.html

I want to open the video clips on the top of the first "watch video link" in the fancybox flowplayer

```
<script>
$("a[class=video]").click(function() {  
  ar vf = $(this).attr("href");  
  $.fancybox('',{  
  'overlayShow'   : true,  
  'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',  
  'transitionOut' : 'elastic',  
  'titlePosition' : 'over', 
  'type' : 'swf', 
  'autoDimensions':false,  
  'centerOnScroll': true,  
  'width' : 800,  
  'height':600,  
  'onComplete' : function() {  
  $("#fancybox-content").html('').flowplayer("flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {clip:{url:vf}});  
}  
});  
return false;  
});  
</script>

<a class="video" href="videos/iBone.HKSTAR.mp4" title="example title text">Watch Video</a>
```